# Why isn't createStructuredSelector sending props to the component?

Tags: reactjs, redux, reselect

I've been learning Redux and I'm using Reselect to memoize the state. Most of my components are working just fine with the selectors, but there's one component where the `createStructuredSelector` function isn't sending part of the data to the component.

```js
const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  currentUser: selectCurrentUser,
  hidden: selectCartHidden
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Header);
```

In fact, only the `hidden` property is going to the component for some reason. `currentUser` just isn't there.

If I go back to use `mapStateToProps` without the selector, it works again.

```js
const mapStateToProps = state => ({
  currentUser: selectCurrentUser,
  hidden: selectCartHidden
})

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Header);
```

Here's the component itself:

```js
const Header = ({ currentUser, hidden }) => (
  <div className="header">
    <Link className="logo-container" to="/">
      <Logo className="logo" />
    </Link>
    <div className="options">
      <Link className="option" to="/shop">SHOP</Link>
      <Link className="option" to="/contact">CONTACT</Link>
      {
        currentUser ?
          <div className="option" onClick={() => auth.signOut()}>SIGN OUT</div>
          :
          <Link className="option" to="/signin">SIGN IN</Link>
      }
      <CartIcon />
    </div>
    {
      hidden ? null : <CartDropdown />
    }
  </div>
)
```

If the problem affected only this component, I wouldn't worry too much, since I could just swap back to what it was without the selector. But for some reason, the `CartDropdown` child component won't rerender without `createStructuredSelector`, even though the state DOES change.

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to reproduce what you experience, must have been a typo or something:

```js
const { Provider, connect } = ReactRedux;
const { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } = Redux;
const { createStructuredSelector } = Reselect;

const initialState = {
  currentUser: 'current user',
  cartHidden: 'cart hidden',
};

const reducer = (state = initialState) => {
  return state;
};
//selectors
const selectCurrentUser = (state) => state.currentUser;
const selectCartHidden = (state) => state.cartHidden;
//creating store with redux dev tools
const composeEnhancers =
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(() => (next) => (action) =>
      next(action)
    )
  )
);
const mapStateToProps = createStructuredSelector({
  currentUser: selectCurrentUser,
  hidden: selectCartHidden,
});

const App = (props) => (
  <pre>{JSON.stringify(props, undefined, 2)}</pre>
);
const ConnectedApp = connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <ConnectedApp />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.5/redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/7.2.0/react-redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/reselect/4.0.0/reselect.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/immer@7.0.5/dist/immer.umd.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

If you are unable to get the **updated** state then I guess you must have mutated the state in your reducers

> But for some reason, the CartDropdown child component won't rerender without createStructuredSelector, even though the state DOES change.

You definitely mutated state in a reducer of worse yet; in a component or action creator.

Comment: I'm paying special attention to the state and all the Redux pieces because this code is part of a course I'm doing. Maybe there really is a typo I couldn't find. Thank you for your answer. I'll update if I find out what's going on.